# Populate Custom List View in Fragment from API

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-custom-view

I want to populate custom list view with Ted Talks from TED API, but nothing is shown. I have done all the efforts but nothing does it.
Here's my code
Fragment Class

```
public class TalksFragment extends ListFragment {

private ListView talkList;
private String TalkUrl = "https://api.ted.com/v1/talks.json?api-key=nm4nq9uyqg558m7z8axbu3be&order=created_at:desc&fields=media_profile_uris,photo_urls,speakers&offset=";
private HandleJSON obj;
private ProgressDialog m_ProgressDialog = null;
private ArrayList<TalksItems> TalkItemsArray = null;
private TalkListAdapter talkListAdapter;
private Runnable viewOrders;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View talks = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talk_list_frag, container, false);
    talkList = (ListView) talks.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    return talks;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    TalkItemsArray = new ArrayList<>();
    this.talkListAdapter = new TalkListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TalkItemsArray);
    talkList.setAdapter(this.talkListAdapter);

    viewOrders = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int Offset=0;
            obj = new HandleJSON(TalkUrl + Offset);
            obj.fetchJSON("Talks");
            while (obj.parsingComplete);
            TalkItemsArray = obj.getTalkItems();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(returnRes);
        }
    };
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
    m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),
            "Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);


}

private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int size = TalkItemsArray.size();
        if(TalkItemsArray != null && TalkItemsArray.size() > 0){
            talkListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
                talkListAdapter.add(TalkItemsArray.get(i));
        }
        m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
        talkListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};



private class TalkListAdapter extends  ArrayAdapter<TalksItems>{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<TalksItems> items;
    public TalkListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<TalksItems> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if(convertView ==  null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_talk, null);
        else
            view = convertView;

        TalksItems TI = items.get(position);
        if(TI != null){
            TextView talkName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTalkName);
            TextView speakerName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtSpeakerName);
            TextView talkDescription = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTalkDescription);
            ImageView talkImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.talkImage);

            talkName.setText(TI.getTalkName());
            speakerName.setText(TI.getSpeakerName());
            talkDescription.setText(TI.getTalkDescription());
            talkImage.setImageURI(TI.getImageURL());
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

}
Where custom_list_talk is layout for custom list and talk_list_frag is layout for fragment having a listview with id "@android:id/list"
API is working correctly, data is coming correctly from API.
Problem is that it shows nothing in custom listview(or may be it is not inflating or etc)

> EDIT
>   Foolish mistake. I didn't call getMethod.

Comment: 1. Is TI != null ?
2. Where's the getCount method of your adapter? Have you confirmed it returns > 0?

Comment: 1. Yes
2. I didn't check adapter, but only data from API. How can I check if adapter returns?

Comment: The question was half wrong on my behalf, you need not implement getCount yourself, but you can do adapter.getCount to check if it actually has items. Also, post your xml files.

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you so much. Very silly problem made by me. I am able to resolve it with the help of your guidance, thank you

Comment: Good to hear. You might want to edit your question with the solution you found of it could be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code you are using

```
obj = new HandleJSON(TalkUrl + Offset);
            obj.fetchJSON("Talks");
```

It should be

```
obj = new HandleJSON(TalkUrl + Offset);
            obj.fetchJSON("talks");//Note the case of KEY
```

JSON is Case Sensitive.

```
**Edit:**
```

Make sure you are not populating the

```
TalkItemsArray
```

In your code.

Comment: I am actually calling fetchJSON to call API for talks
`fetchJSON(string fetchWhat)
{
    //code
    if(fetchWhat == "Talks")
        ReadAndParseTalk(data);
}`

Comment: Ensure once are you getting the json data from the api call.

Comment: Code is too long to paste over here, but I have ensured it.